# Is there a way to force Python function defined under a class to return something (as opposed to nothing) of specific data type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am aware that Python does not have strong typing and that it does not support keywords specifying return types like `void`, `int` and similar in Java and C. I am also aware that we can use type hints to tell the users that they could expect something of specific type in return from a function.

I am trying to implement a Python class which will read a config file (say, a JSON file) that dictates what data transformation methods should be applied on a `pandas` dataframe. The config file looks something like:

```
[
  {
    "input_folder_path": "./input/budget/",
    "input_file_name_or_pattern": "Global Budget Roll-up_9.16.19.xlsx",
    "sheet_name_of_excel_file": "Budget Roll-Up",
    "output_folder_path": "./output/budget/",
    "output_file_name_prefix": "transformed_budget_",

    "__comment__": "(Optional) File with Python class that houses data transformation functions, which will be imported and used in the transform process. If not provided, then the code will use default class in the 'transform_function.py' file.",
    "transform_functions_file": "./transform_functions/budget_transform_functions.py",

    "row_number_of_column_headers": 0,
    "row_number_where_data_starts": 1,
    "number_of_rows_to_skip_from_the_bottom_of_the_file": 0,

    "__comment__": "(Required) List of the functions and their parameters.",
    "__comment__": "These functions must be defined either in transform_functions.py or individual transformation file such as .\\transform_function\\budget_transform_functions.py",
    "functions_to_apply": [
      {
        "__function_comment__": "Drop empty columns in Budget roll up Excel file. No parameters required.",
        "function_name": "drop_unnamed_columns"
      },
      {
        "__function_comment__": "By the time we run this function, there should be only 13 columns total remaining in the raw data frame.",
        "function_name": "assert_number_of_columns_equals",
        "function_args": [13]
      },
      {
        "__function_comment__": "Map raw channel names 'Ecommerce' and 'ecommerce' to 'E-Commerce'.",
        "transform_function_name": "standardize_to_ecommerce",
        "transform_function_args": [["Ecommerce", "ecommerce"]]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

In the `main.py` code, I have something like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # 1. Process arguments passed into the program
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=transform_utils.DESC,
                                     formatter_class = argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter,
                                     usage=argparse.SUPPRESS)
    parser.add_argument('-c', required=True, type=str,
                        help=transform_utils.HELP)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # 2. Load JSON configuration file
    if (not args.c) or (not os.path.exists(args.c)):
        raise transform_errors.ConfigFileError()

    # 3. Iterate through each transform procedure in config file
    for config in transform_utils.load_config(args.c):
        output_file_prefix = transform_utils.get_output_file_path_with_name_prefix(config)
        custom_transform_funcs_module = transform_utils.load_custom_functions(config)

        row_idx_where_data_starts = transform_utils.get_row_index_where_data_starts(config)
        footer_rows_to_skip = transform_utils.get_number_of_rows_to_skip_from_bottom(config)

        for input_file in transform_utils.get_input_files(config):
            print("Processing file:", input_file)
            col_headers_from_input_file = transform_utils.get_raw_column_headers(input_file, config)

            if transform_utils.is_excel(input_file):
                sheet = transform_utils.get_sheet(config)
                print("Skipping this many rows (including header row) from the top of the file:", row_idx_where_data_starts)
                cur_df = pd.read_excel(input_file,
                                       sheet_name=sheet,
                                       skiprows=row_idx_where_data_starts,
                                       skipfooter=footer_rows_to_skip,
                                       header=None,
                                       names=col_headers_from_input_file
                                       )
                custom_funcs_instance = custom_transform_funcs_module.TaskSpecificTransformFunctions()

                for func_and_params in transform_utils.get_functions_to_apply(config):
                    print("=>Invoking transform function:", func_and_params)
                    func_args = transform_utils.get_transform_function_args(func_and_params)
                    func_kwargs = transform_utils.get_transform_function_kwargs(func_and_params)
                    cur_df = getattr(custom_funcs_instance,
                                     transform_utils.get_transform_function_name(
                                         func_and_params))(cur_df, *func_args, **func_kwargs)
```

In `budget_transform_functions.py` file, I have:

```
class TaskSpecificTransformFunctions(TransformFunctions):
    def drop_unnamed_columns(self, df):
        """
        Drop columns that have 'Unnamed' as column header, which is a usual
        occurrence for some Excel/CSV raw data files with empty but hidden columns.
        Args:
            df: Raw dataframe to transform.
            params: We don't need any parameter for this function,
                    so it's defaulted to None.

        Returns:
            Dataframe whose 'Unnamed' columns are dropped.
        """
        return df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains(r'Unnamed')]

    def assert_number_of_columns_equals(self, df, num_of_cols_expected):
        """
        Assert that the total number of columns in the dataframe
        is equal to num_of_cols (int).

        Args:
            df: Raw dataframe to transform.
            num_of_cols_expected: Number of columns expected (int).

        Returns:
            The original dataframe is returned if the assertion is successful.

        Raises:
            ColumnCountMismatchError: If the number of columns found
            does not equal to what is expected.
        """
        if df.shape[1] != num_of_cols_expected:
            raise transform_errors.ColumnCountError(
                ' '.join(["Expected column count of:", str(num_of_cols_expected),
                          "but found:", str(df.shape[1]), "in the current dataframe."])
            )
        else:
            print("Successfully check that the current dataframe has:", num_of_cols_expected, "columns.")

        return df
```

As you can see, I need future implementer of `budget_transform_functions.py` to be aware that the functions within `TaskSpecificTransformFunctions` must always return a `pandas` dataframe. I know that in `Java`, you can create an interface and whoever implements that interface have to abide by the return values of each method in that interface. I'm wondering if we have similar construct (or a workaround to achieve similar thing) in Python.

Hope this lengthy question make sense and I'm hoping someone with a lot more Python experience than I have will be able to teach me something about this. Thank you very much in advance for  your answers/suggestions!

Comment: That's what type hints are for, although they don't force anything unless you configure your IDE to treat type warnings as errors. I'd just write: `def assert_number_of_columns_equals(self, df, num_of_cols_expected) -> Dataframe:`

Comment: *return something (as opposed to nothing)*,what do you want to return?

Comment: You could create an "interface" in Python too, but it won't enforce types either. The only way to actually enforce types is to do manual checks at runtime, or use a tool (like a good IDE) that does static checking for you.

Comment: Runtime checks can be made automatic by implementing `__init_subclass__` in the base class and then wrapping all subclass functions in a function that checks the return type (some kind of automatic decorating functions).

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA, I want to force the future implementer to return `pandas` dataframe. 
I want it such that everybody who adds a function/method in that `TaskSpecificTransformFunctions` class adheres to that rule (return dataframe).

Comment: @Carcigenicate, Thank you. I do plan to add type hints to the functions that I implement. But I want my colleagues to extend `TaskSpecificTransformFunctions` class and if they do, I want them to know that the function they write must return `pandas` dataframe always.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thank you for the response. Could you please share a link/resource where I can read more about the approach you are suggesting?

Comment: Nvm, I lied. I thought protocols might be able to come to the rescue here, but I was wrong.

Comment: @Carcigenicate No worries! Thank you for doing what you can to help me here. :) I also think what I want to do (implementing something like Java's `interface`) is not available (yet) in Python. But I have to try asking SO experts before I make the conclusion. Thank you for your help again!

Comment: @user1330974 Python's abstracts base classes and Python 3.8's `Protocol`s are as close as you can get to interfaces, but they don't do type checking. They only check if a class has the correct methods, and that they have the proper *number* of parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to check the return type of a function at least at run time is to wrap the function in another function that checks the return type. To automate this for subclasses, there is `__init_subclass__`. This can be used in the following way (polishing and handling of special cases needed yet):

```
import pandas as pd

def wrapCheck(f):
    def checkedCall(*args, **kwargs):
        r = f(*args, **kwargs)
        if not isinstance(r, pd.DataFrame):
            raise Exception(f"Bad return value of {f.__name__}: {r!r}")

        return r

    return checkedCall


class TransformFunctions:

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        for k, v in cls.__dict__.items():
            if callable(v):
                setattr(cls, k, wrapCheck(v))



class TryTransform(TransformFunctions):

    def createDf(self):
        return pd.DataFrame(data={"a":[1,2,3], "b":[4,5,6]})


    def noDf(self, a, b):
        return a + b


tt = TryTransform()

print(tt.createDf())   # Works
print(tt.noDf(2, 2))   # Fails with exception
```

Comment: I have tested your suggested solution and it works! But I wanted to ask one more follow-up question. What if I want to implement functions within `TransformFunctions` class and I want them to also adhere to the same rule (that is, return `pandas` dataframe) as its subclasses. Is there a way to achieve that without creating another parent class for `TransformFunctions` class? Thank you in advance for your answer!

Comment: @user1330974 Basically you can factor out the relevant part of `__init_subclass__` in its own function and call it on the `TransformFunctions` class. A bit cleaner but more work can be an own meta class to handle the conversion for all the classes.